# HP Proliant ML350 G5 E200i Hard Disk get amber light after firmware Update

Tags: hp, hard-drive, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array, firmware

I have an HP ProLiant ML 350 G5 with E200i Controler running Windows Server 2008 R2 x64

It have four disks drives models DG072A9BB7 firmware HPD0, with two logical drives C: and D: booth with raid 1-0 runing for months

I add four new disks models DG0072BALVL firmware HPD4, and I add two logical drives E: and F:  booth with raid 1-0

Everything work fine, the WS 2008 R2 recognize the drives C:, D:,  E: and F:

But I upgrade the drivers and firmware with SMART START 8.3 for WS 2008 R2 x64

After reboot the server, the new four hard disks models DG0072BALVL turn on amber light and the drives E: and F: dont appear, the drives C: and D: models DG072A9BB7 still work fine

Pressing F8 boot time controler utility, all four new drives models DG0072BALVL dont appear, only appear the old ones

With HP Array Configuration Utility (ACU), all four new drives models DG0072BALVL dont appear, only appear the old ones

It is hard disk firmware failure ?

Or array disk controler failure ?

Comment: Also, power the server off... remove the power cables... and power the system back on again.

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade the firmware of your RAID controller and all devices. The best approach in your situation is to download a current [HP Firmware Update DVD](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?swItem=MTX-9ed665a89aba447d925937f38b&lang=en&cc=us&mode=3&) (it's bootable), and let it run updates on all of the devices.

Early firmware on the E200i controllers would give false-positive drive failure alerts, etc. It'd best to try to bring everything up to the current revision level.

Try this first. If there's no difference, we can look at the Array Configuration utility to see what it thinks the status of the drives is. But this is more likely to be a firmware problem.

Edit:

**Your array setup is messed up!!**

From the server's perspective, you only have THREE active disks. These are the disks in bay 1, bay 2 and bay 3. The drive in bay 1 is your `C: drive`. It is a RAID-0 and has NO redundancy. Bay 2 and 3 contain a RAID-1 mirror holding your D: drive. No other disks appear.

At this point, I'd check the physical connections of the drives and the internal cabling to the E200i controller.

[image]

Comment: I Will Download the HP Firmware Update DVD to run updates. Thx

Comment: I Downloaded the HP Firmware Update DVD Version 10.10 for WS 2008 R2 x64, the utility upgrade all drives and firmwares that found outdated and have not results, still missing all four new hard disks drives, the old disk still work fine and WS 2008 R2 also

Comment: Please provide a screen shot of what the HP Array Configuration Utility shows. Or, if you can use the hpacucli command line utility, please show the output of `ctrl all show config` and `ctrl all show config detail`.

Comment: Please visit this link [http://www.flickr.com/photos/ricardobalda/](http://www.flickr.com/photos/ricardobalda/) to check the screen shots that I took

Comment: Download [hpacucli output file](http://sdrv.ms/10DXsd3) with all test details